# bootstrap dropdown menu acting weird

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code:

```
<div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container" style="width: auto;">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="/./">Startseite</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                  <a id="drop1" href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Produkte<b class="caret"> </b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop1">
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://google.com">Action</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#anotherAction">Another action</a></li>
                  </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                  <a id="drop2" href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Produkte<b class="caret"> </b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop2">
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://google.com">Action</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#anotherAction">Another action</a></li>
                  </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

it shoud show up like this:

[image]

but it is showing up like this in my code(i click on produkte):

[image]

this is my header in html:

```
<link href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/jquery191.js"></script>
<script src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

why is this? can someone please help me?

thanks a lot

Comment: can you show your `css code` for menu.seems like you have used `float:left` for `li` you need to remove it..

Comment: @sAnS, i dont have my own css. i just included the bootstrap.css, didnot touch it.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/epoyug/1/edit You must have some other CSS interfering.

Comment: works for me as well http://jsfiddle.net/p4XBn/2/ - something in your other css files conflicting

Comment: Yeaah, it was my fault. but thanks sooo much for your help, you guys.

Comment: @doniyor added answer :) ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have used `float:left` for li you need to remove it from you `custom css` file.